# alternative copy constructor in c++

Tags: c++, class, optimization, private, copy-constructor

Edit:
I am going to introduce some badly designed class, this was an old question and I have grown as a programmer since then...

Let's say I have a class with some state and with a method that only uses a part of that state, you will see what I mean:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass(double _1, double _2, double _3)
        : data1(_1)
        , data2(_2)    
        , data3(_3) 
    {}
    void only_uses_data1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data1; ++i)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        data1 = 0; // modifies state
    }
    auto time_the_method() const // this can't modify the instance
    {
        MyClass copy = *this;
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        copy.only_uses_data1();
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        return t2 - t1;
    }
private:
    double data1, data2, data3;
};
```

If you can forgive me for the dumb example, I want to point out that `time_the_method` only uses `data1` as well, so my thought at the time was to create a function that creates a new `MyClass` instance that only copied the element that was needed in the method, and I thought of something like this:

```
// inside MyClass definition
private:
explicit MyClass(const MyClass& other, int) // takes a dummy int
    : data1(other.data1) // copies the necessary data
{}
// usage
MyClass copy(*this, 0);
```

I created what I called at the time a "custom copy constructor" (this name enraged a few people), that takes a dummy variable to change the signature of the constructor.
Furthermore, the dummy variable could actually have some use in the future, maybe switching to an `enum class` instead, this way I could tell the compiler, possibly at compile time with templates, which "custom copy constructor" I need when I want a partial copy in my member functions.

I had this idea because I noticed that when overriding the pre and post increment operators, we have to do something similar:

```
MyClass operator++(int); // pre increment
MyClass& operator++();   // post increment
```

By changing the signature, the compiler is able to know which one to call.

I also realized that this technique was far more appropriate for operator overloading than for constructor overloading.
That is why I asked if anyone had any improvements on this.

I realized that if you have to do something like this, probabily the class itself is poorly designed and it handles too much state, so a code refactor is needed. But anyway, it does not hurt to explore suboptimal solutions, maybe just to understand why the optimal one really is better...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252892/discussion-on-question-by-ugo-capeto-custom-private-specialized-copy-constructor); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do understand that your code is just an example, though I do not understand for what. Note that `MyClass(const MyClass& other, int)` is not a copy constructor. A [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is `MyClass(const MyClass&)` not something else. This distinction is important, because most of the time the copy constructor is called implicitly when you make a copy:

```
 void foo(Example);
 Example a;
 Example b = a; // calls the copy constructor
 foo(b);        // calls the copy constructor
```

`MyClass(const MyClass& other, int)` is not a copy constructor. If you are ok with that then ok. It's just not a constructor that will be invoked implicitly when a copy is made.

> I know that passing a dummy variable is the same process for overloading the prefix and postfix ++operator:

Making use of overload resolution is a good idea. Though you wont get the same effect as with `++`. `++` needs special language support to distinguish between `operator++()` and `operator++(int)`. Your constructor cannot get that support.

I am not entirely sure if you want to keep certain members uninitialized. You should not do that. Rather reconsider your design. If `MyClass` does more than you need in certain places then thats a design smell. Very likely `MyClass` is doing too much for a single class (cf. single responsibility principle).

However, if you want a constructor that does some sort of copying accessible only to one function, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass;

void foo(MyClass&);

struct Proxy {
    MyClass& object;
private:
    Proxy(MyClass& object) : object(object) {}
    friend void foo(MyClass&);
};

struct MyClass  {
    MyClass() = default;
    MyClass(const Proxy& p) {} // implement special copy here
    MyClass(const MyClass&) = default; // copy constructor
};

void foo(MyClass& a) {
    MyClass b = Proxy(a);
}

int main() {
    MyClass a;
    MyClass b = Proxy(a); // fails to compile
}
```

Note how `foo` gets only access to `MyClass(const Proxy& p)` but not to any private parts that `MyClass` might have.